# Can't send Emails with Symfony Application but console works

Tags: php, symfony, smtp, swiftmailer, mail-server

I have an old project in front of me. Application-generated emails do not arrive. But If I use following command they arrive.

```
php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send -vvv --from=example@example.org --to=example@example.org --subject=mailTest --body=testSMTP --env=prod
```

Console and application should use the same parameters.

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_host:       MYSUBDOMAIN.MYHOSTER.net
mailer_port:       587
mailer_user:       myexample@exampleemail.org
mailer_password:   password
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_encryption: ssl
```

Application was developed with Symfony 3.1.4 and Swiftmailer 2.3.

Can you give me an advice, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you use the same environment?

Comment: The command you are using is of swift mailer bundle, but you have not mentioned any code from your application that you use to send the emails. Can you provide more details? Thanks!

Comment: it could be configured that mails sent from application are waiting in a queue to be sent. for that e.g. a cron job would be required to regularly call the console command. this approach is even recommend for some prod environments to not block the application/php script by sending mails.